# Uncountably Many Copies of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology

Is the disjoint union of uncountably many copies of $\mathbb{R}$ metrizable?

Edit: As suggested by the comments, I am referring to the disjoint union topology (I am asking whether the disjoint union of uncountably many copies of $\mathbb{R}$ with disjoint union topology is metrizable if $\mathbb{R}$ has the usual topology)

Comment: Do you mean the long line? That's not metrizable.

Comment: I think they mean that it has the disjoint union topology.

Comment: Hi, what i mean is the disjoint union topology. Sorry for being unclear

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, for instance put a metric bounded by $1$ on $\mathbb{R}$, and then on your disjoint union put this metric on each copy of $\mathbb{R}$, and put distance $2$ on any two elements of different copies.

Comment: +1. For completeness: let $d$ be the usual metric on $\mathbb{R}$, and set $d'(a, b)=\max\{d(a, b), 1\}$. Then $d'$ induces the same topology as $d$. This is the "metric bounded by $1$" referred to.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on what you mean by "disjoint," and I think the distinction itself is even worth highlighting.

I suspect that [this][1]https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_line_(topology) is what you have in mind. This is a set-theoretic disjoint union, but not a topological one. This is not metrizable.

$\mathbb{R^2}$ is a disjoint union of uncountably many copies of the real line, and it certainly has a metric.

If on the third and final hand you mean a metric space homeomorphic to the topological disjoint union (this is not, bu the way, homeomorphic to either of the other spaces) then you can consider a metric space product of the real line with a discrete uncountable space.

In other words, you could say points on the same line have their usual distance, and for points on different lines, just use any fixed positive number.

Comment: I am actually referring to this:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_union_(topology)

Comment: Would the person who -1'd this care to explain? I did correctly answer the question, (option number 3) and I also correctly answered two other questions that a person who stumbles on this page is likely to have in mind.